# An AVPlayerItem can occupy only one position in a player's queue at a time

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller

Im getting this error when trying to play a video from my temp directory:

```
NSString *tmpDir = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NSString *url = [tmpDir stringByAppendingString:videoToPlay];

MPMoviePlayerController *player =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
 initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
```

Why am i getting this error "An AVPlayerItem can occupy only one position in a player's queue at a time."

Isnt that code correct? Am i missing something simple?

Comment: Are your experiencing this on iOS5 beta 2? You should check the Apple Developer Forums, since I solved the same problem following the advice of Peter Harley here https://devforums.apple.com/message/467199. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i am. And that fixed the issue. You are the man!

Answer (score 2):

I tried various solutions provided in apple dev forums. In my case what worked was just changing the source type from streaming to unknown:

// player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

```
  player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following statement to avoid such error. Please keep in mind that, THE sdk that you are using is under NDA.

> [self.mPlayer.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleDefault];

Answer (score 0):

try to check control style and source type.
Im getting this error ,and when change source type to unknow(auto detect,maybe) It goes right.

Answer (score 0):

I got this because i had invalid parameters for movieSourceType, i thought you were supposed to put a MPMovieMediaTypeMask in there (video/audio,etc) but instead you are supposed to put a MPMovieSourceType. Fixing that made it work for me

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when trying to use `replaceCurrentItem` on my `AVQueuePlayer`.

Apple states you should NOT use this method with AVQueuePlayer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390806-replacecurrentitemwithplayeritem

Instead I'm testing `removeAllItems()` and `insert(AVPlayerItem, after: AVPlayerItem?)` with a `nil` value for AVPlayerItem.

iOS12 Swift 5.